Уместно ли применять тире и запятую при вводном слове в начале обособленного оборота?

Использовать один из социолектов может как высокообразованный человек, так и вовсе не имеющий образования — например, английский аристократ и житель рабочих кварталов.

Использовать один из социолектов может как высокообразованный человек, так и вовсе не имеющий образования, например английский аристократ и житель рабочих кварталов.


Как можно обосновать расстановку знаков препинания (во втором предложении она соответствует  ПАС Лопатина http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=126, § 93) в первом предложении?
Практика показывает, что сейчас, по крайней мере в публицистике, гораздо чаще употребляют тире и запятую в подобных случаях. Чем это объснить?

Использовать один из социолектов может как высокообразованный человек, так и вовсе не имеющий образования — например, английский аристократ и житель рабочих кварталов.

Здесь оборот рассматривается как присоединительная конструкция. По Розенталю в этом случае должна быть запятая: Работа может быть закончена в ближайшее время, например через неделю.  Вводное слово используется в качестве присоединительного слова (союза).

Но это в незначительно распространенном предложении, при этом произношение соответствующее. В то же время при наличии собственных знаков как в обороте, так и в самом предложении желательно поставить тире и сделать увеличенную паузу. Это не противоречит правилам. В этом случае вводное слово входит в состав оборота и отделяется запятой.

Часто ли применяется такое оформление? Трудно сказать, в Карте слов не нашлось таких примеров.

Я бы поставила тире в таком предложении:


Как правило, это происходит при возникновении ситуаций, не соответствующих жизненному опыту человека, таких, как стихийные бедствия или большие катастрофы — например, война или революция, а также инфляция.
